# unexpected end of file error in mysqldump via php script

Tags: php, linux, backup, mysql

I am just using mysqldump from php script , but it gives error saying unexpected end of file.
Please help , am stuck up.

```
 **Error:**

   sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
    X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
    Content-type: text/html
```

Following is **mybackupscript.php** :

```
$command = "mysqldump  -u myuser -pmypass mydb > mybkp/backup.sql ";

exec($command, $ret_arr, $ret_code);
```

If i use :

```
$command = "mysqldump  > mybkp/backup.sql ";
```

it works successfully.

If i use :

```
$command = "mysqldump --all -databases > mybkp/backup.sql ";
```

error occurs saying : **mysqldump: unknown option '-b'**
Also, it creates the file backup.sql with the content : 
**Warning: The option '--all' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use --create-options instead.**

Comment: in any of the case, is `mybkp/backup.sql` filled with the expected data dump?

Comment: no , when i run mysqldump  > mybkp/backup.sql  ,then it fills the file  with the content : mysqldump [options] databases tables OR ....

Comment: where are you getting that error message given at the top i.e. `**Error:** ...`? when you dump `$ret_arr` ?

Comment: the error messages comes on my email

Comment: when i dump $ret_arr , then it shows the output : print_r($ret_code) :  Array ( ) 1  ,
ret_code : 2

Comment: are you using `cron` to run this script ?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17330/discussion-between-sqlchild-and-air4x)

Comment: still waiting for a complete solution :(

Answer (score 1):

The below command is syntactically incorrect.

```
$command = "mysqldump --all -databases > mybkp/backup.sql ";
```

It should [be](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_all-databases)

```
$command = "mysqldump -u myuser -p mypass --all-databases > mybkp/backup.sql ";
```

EDIT:

Added the `-u` and `-p` flag. Ensure that you post your MySQL user name after `-u` and MySQL password after `-p`

Comment: dear sir, when i used this correct syntax , then it says--------- mysqldump: Got error: 1045: Access denied for user 'myuser'@'localhost' (using password: NO) when trying to connect--------------------myuser is the username of my website cpanel

Comment: there should no be that `space` between `-p` and `mypass`

Comment: still it says----------sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.2.17
Content-type: text/html